# Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for '{{node sequential_15/conv2d_26/Conv2D}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

After try the model.fit:

```
hist = model.fit(train, epochs=15, validation_data=val, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

I receive the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In\[132\], line 1
\----\> 1 hist = model.fit(train, epochs=15, validation_data=val, callbacks=\[tensorboard_callback\]) #mudei epocas pra 3, antes era 20

File \~\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python310\\site-packages\\keras\\src\\utils\\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.\<locals\>.error_handler(\*args, \*\*kwargs)
67     filtered_tb = \_process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
\---\> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
71 finally:
72     del filtered_tb

File \~\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\__autograph_generated_filea6t43riq.py:15, in outer_factory.\<locals\>.inner_factory.\<locals\>.tf__train_function(iterator)
13 try:
14     do_return = True
\---\> 15     retval_ = ag_\_.converted_call(ag_\_.ld(step_function), (ag_\_.ld(self), ag_\_.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
16 except:
17     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\Enenon\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1338, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\Enenon\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1322, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\Enenon\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1303, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\Enenon\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1080, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "C:\Users\Enenon\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    
    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'conv2d_26' (type Conv2D).
    
    Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for '{{node sequential_15/conv2d_26/Conv2D}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](sequential_15/Cast, sequential_15/conv2d_26/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp)' with input shapes: [64,64,1,1], [3,3,1,32].
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'conv2d_26' (type Conv2D):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(64, 64, 1, 1), dtype=float32)`
```

My code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(64,64,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(64,64,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile('adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
logdir='logs'
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir)

hist = model.fit(train, epochs=15, validation_data=val, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

I am working with a 64,64,1 dataset. This is the code modifying the tensor from 64,64 to 64,64,1 and creating the dataset from the tensors:

```
x = x.reshape(-1, 64, 64, 1)
labels = tf.constant(y)
features = tf.constant(x)
datax = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(features)
datay = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(labels)
data = tf.data.Dataset.zip((datax,datay))
data_iterator = data.as_numpy_iterator()
batch = data_iterator.next()
```